# Wordpress- can I include wp-config to get db details

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a change to an existing WordPress site on the checkout page so that when the user types a suburb/postcode, it looks up the list from a database.

Rather than writing the code to connect to MySQL, is their a PHP file I can include from the Wordpress directories that include the connection?

If not, is their any problem in including `wp-config.php` to get the database details and connect from their?

Comment: All these answers are hacks to deal with the ugly truth that WordPress loads through its config file, rather than only defining constants/variables within it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WPDB after including the necessary files, change the directory to fit your needs:

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php';
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php';
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
```

Oh and if you don't know what it is: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 1):

I might add that a better way is to include those two lines to get access to all WordPress functions and classes:

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );  
require('wp-blog-header.php'); #adapt to match your path
```

The [`WP_USE_THEMES`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12919/what-is-the-constant-wp-use-themes-for) is set to `false` so that theme files aren't loaded.

Answer (score 0):

when I used

```
require_once "../wp-config.php";
```

I've got the error "We're sorry, you are not allowed to proceed"

It is happend because wp-config.php includes wp-settings.php and goes on to connect other files.
So if you create empty file wp-settings.php in your dir and redeclare ABSPATH to your dir, you can use wp-config.php in your scripts. Here's the example:

1. create empty file yourDirName/wp-settings.php
2. use this code to connect wp-config.php

   define ('ABSPATH','yourDirName/');
   require_once "../wp-config.php";

Answer (score -1):

If you only want `access to wp-config.php` without the rest of the Wordpress functions.

Do the following steps:

1: create a empty `wp-settings.php` file in your plugin directory

2: ad this to your php file

```
define( 'ABSPATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-content/plugins/YOUR_PLUGIN_DIR/' );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' );
```

This works perfect for `WordPress 4.2.4` "down and up" and
I tested it in our own plugin mywebapplets.

Comment: you tick wp-config, to load empty wp-settings (and stop the chain loading of other files). This part is good .. but you change `ABSPATH` .. and if some one tries to use it after your plugin is loaded ... it will be fun